# IAM Action for `Get-EC2Instance` command in Powershell SDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Calling `Get-EC2Instance` from EC2 instance and getting

```
Get-EC2Instance : You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Which IAM action do I need to add to my policy?

Comment: Looks like it probably uses `ec2:DescribeInstances`.

Comment: I tried `ec2:Describe*` to no avail. I've ended up using `ec2:*` as a sledgehammer which works but I'm not comfortable with it

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same Unauthorized issue with `Get-EC2Instance` in PowerShell. To get this to work, attach the permissions below to your role policy. Looks like the `DescribeNetworkInterfaces` permission is required in addition to `DescribeInstances`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```